# Webpack in JavaScript shows: Error: Unknown option '--watch-content-base'

Tags: javascript, html, react-fullstack

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --watch-content-base  --open",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

shows the  error:---

> frontend@1.0.0 start
> webpack-dev-server --watch-content-base  --open

[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--watch-content-base'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options

I cannot understand why I'm getting this error considering in the video I was following it works just fine. If I remove ' --watch-content-base' it works but I'm trying to make sure any code changes are automatically updated on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of a different of versions. v5 has this change that watchContentBase is no more a valid option. It is replaced by static.

Try running this:

```
npx webpack serve --static-watch
```

Related [comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2958#issuecomment-757141969)

Comment: please elaborate where i have to edit the code.